# Azure Cognitive Search: got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_language' in python vscode

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cognitive-search, semantic-search

I'm trying to use semantic search enabled azure cognitive search in my flask app (in python virtual env).
When I do pip install azure.search.documents, 11.3.0 version gets installed
and I get following error:

```
TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_language'
```

same for query_speller, semantic_configuration_name etc.

here is the code I'm using:

```
results = list(
             self.search_client.search(search_text="xxx", 
                                            query_type ="semantic", 
                                            query_language  ="en-us",
                                            query_speller  ="lexicon", 
                                            semantic_configuration_name  ="xxx", 
                                            top=3, 
                                            captions= None)
```

below code works fine

```
results = list(self.search_client.search(search_text="xxx"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same error that occurs when I try with **`azure-search-documents=11.3.0`** package in my environment.

> TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_language'

[image]

You can use the below code and package to get the semantic search enabled Azure cognitive search.

**Package:**

```
pip install azure-search-documents==11.4.0b3
```

**Code:**

```
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

  endpoint = "AZURE_SEARCH_SERVICE_ENDPOINT"
  index_name = "AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME"
  api_key = "AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY"

credential = AzureKeyCredential(api_key)
client = SearchClient(endpoint=endpoint,
                          index_name=index_name,
                          credential=credential)
results = list(client.search(search_text="Budget Room", 
                                            query_type ="semantic", 
                                            query_language  ="en-us",
                                            query_speller  ="lexicon", 
                                            semantic_configuration_name  ="semantic", 
                                            top=3))
print(results)
```

**Output:**

The above code was executed and successfully get the required results.

```
[{'LastRenovationDate': '2014-10-31T00:00:00Z', 'Category': 'Budget', 'Description': 'The Best Gaming Resort in the area.  With elegant rooms & suites, pool, cabanas, spa, brewery & world-class gaming.  This is the best place to play, stay & dine.', 'ParkingIncluded': False, 'Tags': ['continental breakfast', 'bar', 'pool'], 'Location': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-106.605949, 35.1087], 'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}}}, 'Description_fr': "La meilleure station de jeux dans la région.
```

[image]

Also, make sure your Semantic search is enabled for your service.

**Reference:**
[Azure.search.documents.SearchClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.searchclient?view=azure-python#azure-search-documents-searchclient-search)

Answer (score -1):

Semantic search is still in preview and only available in beta versions.

Please try install latest beta version of azure-search-documents library.

(I work in the SDK team in MS)